# Java Interthread Communication not passing message object

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, communication

To communicate between threads, I followed the Oracle [Guarded Blocks example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html), which readily compiles and runs. My architecture is slightly different, as my consumer spawns the producer task, though I tried this variation with the example and it works perfectly.

The pertinent code from my main program;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
    FrameMsg frameMsg = new FrameMsg();
    AwarenessAnalytics awarenessAnalytic = new AwarenessAnalytics(frameMsg);
    awarenessAnalytic.start();
```

The pertinent code from the consumer thread;

```
public class AwarenessAnalytics extends Thread implements MotionEventListener{
    FrameMsg frameMsg;
    FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionDetection;

      public AwarenessAnalytics(FrameMsg frameMsg) {
        this.frameMsg = frameMsg;
        System.out.println("AwarenessAnalytic frameMsg = " + this.frameMsg.hashCode());
        }
 AdvancedVideoAnalytics tempIntermediateVA;
 tempIntermediateVA = new AdvancedVideoAnalytics(frameMsg);

public void run() {

    tempIntermediateVA.start();

    while (true) {
        // TODO: create loop to process frames from each video stream
        frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection();
        // interthread message from AdvancedAnalytic
        System.out.println("Waiting for FrameMsg");
        frameWithMotionDetection = frameMsg.take();
        System.out.println("FrameMsg received");
}
```

The pertinent code from the producer task;

```
public class AdvancedVideoAnalytics extends Thread {
  FrameMsg frameMsg;
  FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionDetection;

public AdvancedVideoAnalytics (FrameMsg frameMsg) {
    this.frameMsg = frameMsg;
    System.out.println("AdvancedVideoAnalytic frameMsg = " + this.frameMsg.hashCode());
 }

// the run method includes;

// Send frame and any clusters detected
// as frameMsg
frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection();

frameWithMotionDetection.setMotionData(contourAnalysisResults);

frameWithMotionDetection.setCurrentFrame(frameToExamine);
System.out.println("Preparing to send message to AwarenessAnalytics thread");
frameMsg.put(frameWithMotionDetection);
```

The FrameMsg class;

```
public class FrameMsg {
// Message sent from video stream monitors to analytic fusion engine

private FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionData;

//private String message;
// True if consumer should wait
// for producer to send message,
// false if producer should wait for
// consumer to retrieve message.
private boolean empty = true;

public synchronized FrameWithMotionDetection take() {
    // Wait until message is
    // available.
    System.out.println("Getting ready to take frameWithMotionData");
    while (empty) {
        try {
            wait(10);
            System.out.println("Waiting to take frameWithMotionData because empty = true");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    // Toggle status.
    empty = true;
    System.out.println("Successfully took frameWithMotionData, empty = " + empty);
    // Notify producer that
    // status has changed.
    notifyAll();
    return frameWithMotionData;
}

public synchronized void put(FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionData) {
    // Wait until message has
    // been retrieved.
    System.out.println("Getting ready to put frameWithMotionData");
    while (!empty) {
        try { 
            System.out.println("Waiting to put frameWithMotionData because empty = false");
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    // Toggle status.
    empty = false;
    // Store message.
    this.frameWithMotionData = frameWithMotionData;
    System.out.println("Successfully put frameWithMotionData, empty = " + empty);
    // Notify consumer that status
    // has changed.
    notifyAll();
}
```

}

Interestingly, all of the frameMsg object ids are the same, and I am able to 'put' a frameMsg and set empty to false from the producer. However, the frameMsg object seen by the consumer always returns 'true' for empty.

The output extract looks like;

```
VideoAnalyticsUnitTest frameMsg = 1704856573
AwarenessAnalytic frameMsg = 1704856573
AdvancedVideoAnalytic frameMsg = 1704856573

Waiting to take frameWithMotionData because empty = true
Waiting to take frameWithMotionData because empty = true
(many of these)...
Preparing to send message to AwarenessAnalytics thread
Getting ready to put frameWithMotionData
Successfully put frameWithMotionData, empty = false
Waiting to take frameWithMotionData because empty = true
Preparing to send message to AwarenessAnalytics thread
Getting ready to put frameWithMotionData
Waiting to put frameWithMotionData because empty = false
Waiting to take frameWithMotionData because empty = true
Waiting to take frameWithMotionData because empty = true
Waiting to take frameWithMotionData because empty = true
```

And it continues like that last three lines until I terminate the program.

I'm perplexed because;
1. I followed the example
2. The object IDs match

Yet, the consumer never sees a non-empty frameMsg (which is a complex object).

Have I missed something obvious?

I was initially using a listener to send messages, but I didn't want a huge application taking up listener space. Now reading more of the comments, it seems I could use the listener and pass the msg to the run portion of the consumer with a Blocking Queue.

If this were you, would you pursue the communications approach above, or revert back to a listener with a blocking queue?

Comment: The code, as you posted it, does not compile. Can you check it and add the contents of the run() methods of AwarenessAnalytics and AdvancedVideoAnalytics. Also, the take() and put() methods are not called anywhere in the code.

Comment: Ok, just added the key lines of the run methods. There would be far too much code if I included all of the code.

Comment: This is way far from a SSCCE

Comment: Apologies, Giulio Franco, I'll try to remove as much as possible while leaving the pertinent sections.

Comment: I have removed any superfluous code, thanks for the suggestion, Giulio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bhargav Modi points out, the code is running into the finer issues of writing multi-threaded applications (synchronized-block versus -method, using `volatile` declarations on key variables). These issues are often missed during testing since an element of chance is required to make the issues appear (one of the most notorious ones is [double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)).

This is a good reason to use the [Java concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) classes: there is less chance of writing code that is not thread-safe or has multi-threading issues. In your case, the [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) looks like a good replacement. With the SynchronousQueue there is no need to use the `empty` variable, the `this.frameWithMotionData` variable or the wait/notifyAll mechanics.

Comment: I have taken your suggestion and tweaked it slightly by implementing the ArrayBlockingQueue, which is now working as needed. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

don't use `synchronized` method if want to update `empty` parameter rather use 
`synchronized` block

```
synchronized(this){
//work from here for core logic 

}
//empty =true logic or empty = false
```

Blocks do have advantages over methods, most of all in flexibility because you can use other object as lock whereas syncing the method would lock the complete class.

Compare:

```
// locks the whole object
... 
private synchronized void someInputRelatedWork() {
... 
}
private synchronized void someOutputRelatedWork() {
... 
}
```

Vs.

```
// Using specific locks
Object inputLock = new Object();
Object outputLock = new Object();

private void someInputRelatedWork() {
synchronize(inputLock) { 
    ... 
} 
}
private void someOutputRelatedWork() {
synchronize(outputLock) { 
    ... 
}
}
```

Also if the method grows you can still keep the synchronized section separated:

```
 private void method() {
 ... code here
 ... code here
 ... code here
 synchronized( lock ) { 
    ...very few lines of code here
 }
 ... code here
 ... code here
 ... code here
 ... code here
}
```

and last suggestion is to use `LinkedBlockingQueue` as it has good performance hit and has good methods `put and take`

Comment: There may be some merit to your suggestion, pls help me understand why the block is superior to the method in this situation.

Comment: @Will check my updated answer and give upvote if you consider it as a logical reason

Comment: Excellent explanation, Bhargav, thank you very much, this is most helpful

Comment: It helped my understanding and I may use this in the future at some point, though the previous answer is what worked for me, and is more flexible and less complex. If I could set both to 'checked' I would, but I just tried and only one is allowed.